# Can you please explain me the following javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I've been using this code to buy a phone in a flash sale and now that I'm done with with it I want to understand what the following code actually does:

```
setInterval(function (){
  jQuery('.btn').trigger('click');
  console.log('Working...');
}, 10);
```

Comment: Cmon guys.. why the -2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is setting interval of the function using setInterval meaning that the function will be called after every 10 millisecond. The function in it is triggering the click of the element having class btn and then sending data to the log ("WORKING");

```
setInterval(function(){ jQuery('.btn').trigger('click'); console.log('Working...'); },10);
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: @VivekGiri Jquery is a javascript library which is used to make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

It enforce click on element with `.btn` class after 10 miliseconds.

Comment: what if there are more than 1 buttons on the site

Comment: ok then every element within the class .btn will be clicked when i run it?

Comment: It is better to handle click once and delegate to clicked item,by triggering function binded with click